# In an Angular application how can you debug an error like this?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am writing an Angular 12 app and there is an error, and that's all the information I am getting. I am finding very difficult to debug as I can not locate what file the error is in.

It must be better than this, am I missing something?

O and by the way it's not in any of the files listed in the error output.

[image: A unhelpful error]

Comment: It looks like you're using chrome. I would use [pause on any exception](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/automatically-pause-on-any-exception/). It will  stop your app in case the error is thrown, and also show you the line where it happens and the stack trace.

Comment: did you try looking for "orderBy" in your source code ? It seems to be in a subscribe, or in an rxjs operator, which makes it difficult to debug. Since it is in an asyncronous task, you may have a look to your network tab, and see if an API doesn't respond what you were expecting.

Comment: You are running a production version. Can you reproduce in development version where you can see the source map?

Comment: @BennyHalperin the first line of log is "webpack-dev-server", and "angular is running in developpement mode". It must be a development mod configuration issue in the angular.json then.

Comment: @Random may be **webpack** misconfiguration

Comment: you can use Optional Chaining Operator (?.) before orderBy ex. xyz?.orderBy or you can check in .ts file like this
 if (orderBy != null) {
      console.log("orderBy is not null");
}
else{
      console.log("orderBy is null");
}

Comment: Thx everyone... So there are configuration that maybe I am missing that can give better error/exception experience... I did pause on any exception and it traps in index.js, with a stake trace that doesn't help. I have found the orderBy but I was really asking about the whole debugging experience, I kind of expected something better but as you pointed out, maybe it's because of the RxJs async stuff, that's making it difficult.